# execute query defined in column as String

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello again I need some help,
I have table where in column "query" is defined query statement. I would like to run it and as output get the result.For example:

```
Create table table1
(
ID Number,
Query Varchar2(400)
)
insert into table1(id,query) values (1,'select name from table2 where table2.id=table1.id and table2.type = variable');

create table table2
(ID number,
Name varchar2(400),
Type Varchar2(400)
)
insert into table2 values (1,'Mathew','M');
insert into table2 values (1,'Thomas','G');
insert into table2 values (2,'Jerry','P');
```

For now query :

```
'select name from table2 where table2.id=table1.id and table2.type = variable'
```

should return only "Mathew" (assuming variable as 'M' - procedure variable input)

As procedure input I want to have variable which I will replace somehow in query statement.

Could you give me some tips how to handle with that?

------------Edit

I did stmh like that:

```
create or replace procedure queryrun 
(var1 varchar2) as 
str     VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
execute immediate 'select replace(query,''variable'','''||var1||''') from table1' into str;  
dbms_output.put_line('Value is '||str);
END;
```

But as result it present query... no result of select statement...

Comment: First off all your code is mess and doesn't even work (syntax error table creation)

Comment: What do you plan to do with the query results; particularly if different queries have different projections? Ae you going to return a ref cursor, perhaps? (Hopefully you're protecting against SQL injection but that's a bit off-topic)

Comment: I dont get it "If different queries have different projections" - All what I want to return is (int this example) name of table 2 : Mathew

Comment: I updated my question with example code I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only selecting your query, not running it; and you're replacing the string `"'variable'"` - including the single quotes - with your value, but your original query string doesn't have the single quotes around it - so nothing matches.

You should not really substitue a hard-coded value anyway. Change your stored query to include a bind variable placeholder instead:

```
insert into table1(id,query)
values (1,'select name from table2 where table2.id=table1.id and table2.type = :variable');
```

Although that query is invalid anyway - you don't have `table1` defined in the from clause or a join clause. When you have a valid query you can run standalone, use that, but with a bind variable (denoted by the leading colon).

But let's assume you have a valid query string in your table, that will only return one row, say:

```
insert into table1(id,query)
values (1,'select name from table2 where type = :variable');
```

Your procedure then needs a local variable to hold that query string. You select your query into that using static SQL, and then use dynamic SQL via  execute immediate to run the query from that string, and provide the bind value with the `using` clause. The result goes into another local variable, which you are already doing.

So a simple version might look like this:

```
create or replace procedure queryrun (p_var1 varchar2) as
  l_query table1.query%type;
  l_name table2.name%type;
begin
  select query into l_query from table1 where id = 1;
  execute immediate query into l_name using p_var1;  
  dbms_output.put_line('Value is ' || l_name);
end;
```

This is obviously rather contrived. If you have multiple queries in your table, and perhaps pass a second ID variable into the procedure to choose which one to run, they would all have to take a single bind variable, and would have to all be able to put the result into the same type and size of result variable. You're also restricted to queries that return exactly one row. You can adapt and extend this of course, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Great.. It is exactly what I was looking for. Now i see there is a mistake in query statement... Thanks Alex : )

Comment: I have one more question, I'm just wondering, let's assume that our query will looks: 
select name from table2,table1 where type = :variable and typ2 =:variable , Do not ask why : D
As you can see name of variables are the same, I would to avoid use:  using p_var1,p_var1 because I don't now how many :variable query will contain.
Is there any other trick for that?

Comment: @user5506560 - in that case you'd say `and typ2 = type`; but more generally, no. You could use a CTE to make the bind variable available to the main query to use however many times it wants, and only have to set it once. And you could have multiple arguments to the procedure but give them default values (null) so you don't have to pass them; and give them all in the `using` clause in case they're needed - but then you'd have to pass the same value for the first two arguments in this example. This is too big an area for comments though. If you have a real scenario you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have bind variable and use plsql execute immediate.

Examples:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm